# How can I tell who's mission is theirs without the color coding?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm badly color blind and I'm tired of driving miles to be told "Return here with Trevor." or similar, then have to find Trevor who has wandered off onto an island surrounded by bodies in his underwear!

Is there a way to tell who should do each mission without the color coding? I feel silly asking but it's driving me mad!

Comment: It's been a while... but aren't the markers letters? e.g. "T" for Trevor... or is that just the main missions?

Comment: @musefan Some of them do, M for Michael, but others are the name of the person you are meeting. L for Lemar is a simple one (Franklin), but others are not so clear! Then there's strangers and freaks missions and all the side stuff. Sometimes they are only there for the person I'm playing as, sometimes I'm told to return as another.

Comment: Ah yes, I recall now sorry. Like I said, it's been a while

Comment: Thanks anyway, I appreciate the input. It's only some missions, but it's very annoying. It's hard enough for me to read the map at the best of times, but nearly impossible with the colour choices Rockstar made!

Comment: Isn't it an option to take a guide at moments you are uncertain?

Comment: @Mathias711 ha, that's actually so obvious it never occured to me! Yeah I have my phone to hand playing, would be faster to Google it than drive all over the city twice!

Comment: Haha, sometimes you're so stuck in something, you can't think of obvious things, just outside the box. Good luck :)

Comment: Would subtitles help?

Comment: @Brok3n not really to be honest, as sometimes it's just a marker on the map.

Comment: Playguide map printed?

Comment: Wow that sucks.. Good luck man :/

Answer (score 1):

Most missions should be labelled with a letter e.g. M for Michael or T for Trevor. But in some cases there is a different letter e.g. L for Lamar or Lester,in these cases you would have to guess who would be the most likely character e.g. If it's Lamar go with Franklin. Hope this helps.

Edit: there is no way of telling with the strangers and freaks side quests.